# _ctx.function is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, web-frontend

When I call the function within the template and press the button that interacts with the function within the script, it automatically returns a `_ctx.deleteTransaction` is not a function

My template:

```
<template>
<div>
  <navbar></navbar>
  <table v-if="this.history != null" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Moneda</th>
        <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
        <th scope="col">Precio</th>
        <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
        <th scope="col">Movimiento</th>
        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
        <th scope="col">Editar</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in this.history" :key="index">
      <th scope="row">{{ item.crypto_code.toUpperCase() }}</th>
      <td>{{ item.crypto_amount }}</td>
      <td>${{ item.money }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.datetime.slice(0,10) }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.action }}</td>
      <button class="btn btn-danger mb-1" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                  data-bs-target="#modalEliminar" @click="deleteTransaction(item._id)">Eliminar</button>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
          Edit
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure you want to edit this transaction?
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-danger mb-1" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                  data-bs-target="#modalEliminar" @click="deleteTransaction(item._id)">Eliminar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

My Script:

```
export default {
  components: {
    navbar,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      history: null,
      loading: true,
      id: null,
      setIndex: 0,
      money: null,
      error: false,
    };
  },
  setup() {
      
    const id = ref(null);
    const Historial = async() =>{
     await lab3api.getHistorial().then((response) => {
      
        console.log("Data?");
        console.log(response.data);
        this.history = response.data;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
    console.log("pedioo esa");
    
   
    const deleteTransaction = ()=>{ 
      lab3api.delete(id)
      console.log('eliminadoo')
      Historial()
    }
    
    onMounted(()=>{

      Historial()
    })
    //deleteTransaction()
    return{
      id,
      deleteTransaction
    }
  },
};
```

I dont know what else to do. I tried everything, async functions, OnClick, use methods: from vue 2, everything, and I cant do it

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. You return deleteTransaction from setup so it's available in a template, the error shouldn't be there - unless setup function throws an error, and you can see this in console. You're mixing composition and options api, this is a mistake, it will cause other errors

Comment: Yes I know, however if I don't use this.history from template my information isn't displayed, it does if I use this.history from options api.

I honestly don't know how to go about displaying the information I need and calling a function from the template. i thought i was doing right

Comment: Using `this.history` inside `<template>` is a mistake. You should use `history` directly. And @Estus is correct. Do not mix Options API with Composition. Inside `setup` function, use `const state = reactive({ /* your data options here */})` and `return { /* other stuff */, ...toRefs(state) }`. This effectively replaces `data` function, but in Composition API syntax.

Comment: `this` is redundant in a template, it's a mistake to use it in setup